# Where can I buy bitcash

Tags: blockchain-fork, segregated-witness, segwit2x

Is there any where I can buy bitcash ahead of the fork? Or do I need to keep my bitcoin in wallets that won't signal SegWit?

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin Cash is technically just Bitcoin before the fork, it doesn't really exist as such, and any Bitcoin you own will become Bitcoin Cash as well after the fork (because your UTXOs will be valid in the shared chain before the fork and thus valid in both branches). Until the fork happens, there is only one blockchain, hence the term fork.

Comment: Is there a way of knowing which side a miner will vote? ie. the electrum wallet says it wont add segwit...will keeping bit here turn to bitcash after 1Aug?

Comment: Electrum wallet is not a miner, I'm unsure what you mean. For more info on the chain split check out some of the other questions on SE, e.g. https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/56661/what-happens-to-my-bitcoins-if-a-hard-fork-occurs but if you have further questions, please start a new topic rather than using the comments